# display image in jquery dialog using html body

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display an image in jquery dialog using html body

```
body = "<table><tr><td><b>Image :</b></td><td><img id ="image" width="50" height="50" alt="" src="images/sample.png"></img></td></tr></table>";

document.getElementById('JQUERYDialogDiv').innerHTML = body;
```

But this is  not working for me , any suggestions would be appreciated .

Comment: Escape your double quotes?

Comment: are there any error you're seeing?

Comment: @TZHX Which double quotes? I mean of which keyword like src,id etc

Comment: #khakiout  : Also there are no errors . just the image is not getting displayed.

Comment: PLEASE DON`T USE CAPS. THEY ARE NEVER APPROPIATE. FURTHERMORE READ THIS: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot  for your input. I  finally   got the solution need to add context path `a src="<%request.getContextPath();%>/images/sample.png"`

Answer (score 0):

You should escape your quotes within the string. Your `body` assignment is being pre-terminated by the double quotes in the id, width and other attributes.

```js
body = "<table><tr><td><b>Image :</b></td><td><img id=\"image\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\" alt=\"\" src=\"images/sample.png\"></img></td></tr></table>";
document.getElementById('JQUERYDialogDiv').innerHTML = body;
```

```html
<div id="JQUERYDialogDiv"></div>
```

Or just based on the comment below, replace the double quotes of the string with single quotes. Like this, just be sure that there are no single quotes inside the string. TBH, I prefer escaping the quotes inside the string.

```
body = '<table><tr><td><b>Image :</b></td><td><img id ="image" width="50" height="50" alt="" src="images/sample.png"></img></td></tr></table>';
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could enclose the string in a single quotes to aid readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes in beginning to work.

```html
body = '<table><tr><td><b>Image :</b></td><td><img id ="image" width="50" height="50" alt="" src="images/sample.png"></img></td></tr></table>';
document.getElementById('JQUERYDialogDiv').innerHTML = body;
```